# Show document library url in search results

Tags: search, 2007, xslt

When editing the XSLT for the search results web part I'd like to know when the result represents a document or, for that matter, a list item and then.. I'd like to be able to display a link to the library rather than only deep-linking directly to the document.

Do you think that a substring with last-index-of ("/") XSLT would be the best way to omit the document-name itself from the search results so that you can send someone to the document library or folder where the search result resides?

Answer (score 1):

Matthew McDermott posted some XSLT scripts, including one that does this, on CodePlex here:  http://sctxsl.codeplex.com/releases/view/12070